# How can I get a chrome extension to affect the webpage itself? (not the popup)

Tags: html, json, google-chrome, background, google-chrome-extension

I have been reading the [dev guide](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devguide.html) but haven't been able to work out how to put my own codes into webpages

I know it is possible because AVG uses it (in it's link scanner), and FastestChrome extension uses it too (highlight something and a link to a search pops up).

I have a backgrounded page but I can't get it to effect the webpages I go on (permissions are correct as I can get css to effect)

I am probably missing something really simple :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not intuitively presented in the documentation but your background page can not access the current webpage b/c they are in different contexts. In other words the background page is it's own separate page so it has no access to any other page's DOM.

If you want to affect the page the user is viewing in the browser you will need to use what is referred to as a "content script".

If you want to communicate between content scripts and the background page you will need to refer to the [message passing API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html). Check out [my extension's source code](https://github.com/sym3tri/CSS-Inject) for reference. I do exactly that.

Just remember...

**Background Page**: used for general logic in your extension, not anything page specific.

**Content Scripts**: are loaded into every page the user sees, and can manipulate that specific page.

Answer (score 1):

Those probably use [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) to inject Javascript into webpages. These scripts run in the context of the web pages and can access the DOM.
You can either define a script to always run in a web page by declaring the script file in the extension manifest, or you can use your background page to inject a script when needed.